Quasar Vue QCard - how to make card content in a row the same height?
I have a Quasar Vue 3 component I'm trying to put together that consists of a row of QCards. The q-card-section's of each card in the row has different content lengths.  I'd like for the q-card-section heights to match across the row regardless, to allow the action buttons to occupy the same positions at the bottom of the card  After messing around with this for many hours, I have not been able to figure this out.  The code below creates the following output, which would be perfect if I could get the content in Card 1 to occupy the same height as Card 2, shifting the action buttons down to the same location on the bottom of the card. I thought flex-grow would allow for that, but it doesn't seem to.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
close but not quite layout
Here's my existing component code:
`

  <div>
    <div class="row items-stretch">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <q-card class="full-height">
          <q-card-section>
            <div class="text-h6">Card 1</div>
            <div class="text-subtitle2">Card 1 content</div>
          </q-card-section>
          <q-separator />
          <q-card-actions align="right">
            <q-btn no-caps color="brand">Go to One</q-btn>
          </q-card-actions>
        </q-card>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <q-card class="full-height">
          <q-card-section style="flex-grow:1">
            <div class="text-h6">Card 2</div>
            <div class="text-subtitle2">More content of a different "size"<br />include extra lines</div>
          </q-card-section>
          <q-separator />
          <q-card-actions align="right">
            <q-btn no-caps color="brand">Go to Two</q-btn>
          </q-card-actions>
        </q-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'CardRow'
  // Add your component logic here
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  /* Customize styles as needed */
  .full-height {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>`

`
